# Having trouble setting the Java classpath from terminal

Tags: java, macos, terminal, classpath

My directories are structured as follows: `/User/JAVA/MyProject/`

In the `MyProject` folder, I have my `Main.java` and `Helper.java` files

In the `JAVA` folder, I have two JAR files: `jar1.jar` and `jar2.jar`

I would like to set my classpath to these two JARs so I can use them in my `Main.java` and `Helper.java` files. Very simple.

To do this, I have tried the following (as well as numerous other variations) from my terminal:

<s>user:MyProject$ javac -cp "/User/JAVA/jar1.jar:/User/JAVA/jar2.jar:." Main.java</s>

*EDIT: I am now using this command, as suggested, and receiving the same errors*

```
user:MyProject$ javac -cp "/User/JAVA/jar1.jar:/User/JAVA/jar2.jar:." Helper.java Main.java
```

From what I've read, this should work. I have specified the absolute locations of the two JARs, I have separated them by a colon `:` (I am on OSX), and I have also included my current directory `.`. Then I have specified the file containing my `main` method with `Main.java`.

Unfortunately, I keep receiving a "Cannot find symbol" for the classes' methods in the JARs when I try to compile.

<s>Furthermore, when I try `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));`, I receive the following output `.`, indicating my classpath is still set  to my current directory.</s>

---

My error is this:

```
/User/JAVA/MyProject/Helper.java:13 cannot find symbol
symbol: variable StdOut
location: class Helper
```

*To note:*
When I opened my project up in Eclipse and added the classpath via the IDE, everything worked as expected and no error messages appeared during compilation. Nevertheless, I still would like to figure out how to do this from terminal and without the IDE.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: In which of the two files you have declared the variable `StdOut`?

Comment: StdOut is a class declared in Jar1, which is being used in Helper. this must not have anything to do with the classpath then, I assume.

Comment: @JohnZ the error is teiing you you using `StdOut` as a **variable**. If you don't understand the issue, posting the code for `Helper.java` will let us point out the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Using `-cp` when compiling or running sets the classpath. That overrides (ignores) anything you would have put in the env variable CLASSPATH.

Since you didn't post the actual error you're receiving I'm going to guess the missing symbol is from *your other class* that `Main` is referencing. Add it to the command:

> javac -cp "/User/JAVA/jar1.jar:/User/JAVA/jar2.jar:." Helper.java Main.java

**Edit due to the OP posting the actual error:** You have a an error in your class that makes it uncompilable. It has nothing to do with jar files or classpaths. You are attempting to use / reference a variable named `StdOut` that doesn't exist.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and I still receive the error, which I have added above. For all classes declared in the JAR files, when used in my Main or Helper files, I get a  "Cannot find symbol..." error message.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the semicolon paths separator (;), as discribed in [Setting the classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) document.
But you are using colon instead (:).

Try to use the following command (copy and paste it):

```
javac -cp /User/JAVA/jar1.jar;/User/JAVA/jar2.jar Helper.java Main.java
```

from your `/User/JAVA/MyProject` directory.

**EDIT:**

All above is for Windows.

The problem is in paths themselves.

Comment: This is interesting. I'm getting a "Permission Denied." I tried it with a "sudo javac..." and received the same message. What might this be?

Comment: @JohnZ Are you the owner of /User/JAVA directory? Check it with `ls -la /User/JAVA` command in terminal. Your username is JAVA, by the way?

Comment: I receive a "-rw-r--r--@" for both jar files, whereas for my MyProject folder, I have "drwxr-xr-x".

Comment: @JohnZ Sorry. I've asked you the wrong question. What is your username? JAVA? Who is the owner of the /User/JAVA directory? You'll see it if you run `ls -la /User` command.

Comment: I am logged in on the admin account, but I am getting a "staff" rather than "admin". And the staff's permissions are read only. I should change this to read and write?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45670/discussion-between-mockertim-and-johnz)

Comment: Erm, not to be picky but `;` is for use in windows (and you linked to the windows docs). `:` is used in *nix and isn't his problem, nor is any of this other stuff in the comments.

Comment: @Brian Roach Right you are. My bad.

Comment: re: your edit, it has nothing to do with paths. The OP updated their question. They have a syntax error (or worse) in `Helper.java` - they are trying to use a variable (`StdOut`) that has not been declared in their code. e.g. `System.out.println(foo)` where `foo` was never declared.